# When does a MDB acknowledges JMS queue for message read

Tags: jms, ejb, weblogic12c

I have an MDB deployed on Weblogic 12c, which reads from messages from JMS queue(UDQ). The message is being read by the MDB but it's not being removed from JMS queue, which is causing the messages to be read repeatedly.
So, I want to know when does MDB acknowledges JMS queue that it read the message successfully and queue should remove that message.

Answer (score 0):

MDB acknowledge mode depends on Non-Transacted/Transacted Session type. Non-Transacted Session has five acknowledge modes:

- AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE
- CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
- DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE
- NO_ACKNOWLEDGE
- MULTICAST_NO_ACKNOWLEDGE

Description: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jms/fund.html, Table 2-7 Acknowledge Modes Used for Non-Transacted Sessions

When you create a transacted session, the acknowledge mode is ignored. When an application commits a transaction, all the messages that the application received during the transaction are acknowledged by the messaging system.

So check your Session Type and then, if you use Non-Transacted session, check acknowledge mode. You can use "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" -> Acknowledgment is the last thing to happen implicitly after the onMessage() handler returns.

You can set AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE via

@MessageDriven(name = "queueMdb", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
}